# How to get "node_modules" folder content back

Tags: react-native

I have deleted the folder: "node_modules" from root folder(gave the source code to someone) because I think this contain packages that we can get any time.

How can I get those files back?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have a `package.json` in your directory?  If so, you can run `npm i` to reinstall the project dependencies ( a.k.a bring back your `node_modules` ).

Answer (score 3):

You must have a `package.json` in your source's root folder. If that's the case, do `$ npm install`, it will rebuild all modules.

If you don't have `package.json`, run `$ npm init`, add your modules, then run `$npm install`.

Comment: @prateek Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.